# Print function macro definition in gdb

Tags: c, gcc, macros, gdb

Here is the source file fragment:

```
#define TEST 34
#define PRINT_CONCAT(a, b) \
    printf("%d\n", a##b)
```

Compiling with `GCC` and linking this source file into a binary with flags `-ggdb3 -O3` and running the app with `gdb` shows up the following behavior:

```
(gdb) p TEST                                                                                                                                                                                                       
$3 = 34                                                                                                                                                                                                            
(gdb) p PRINT_CONCAT                                                                                                                                                                                               
No symbol "PRINT_CONCAT" in current context.
```

Is there a way to make gdb expand function macros in any way?

Comment: To see the effect of the macro, run just the preprocessor and examine the locations where the macro has been used...

Comment: @Fe2O3 It might be an approach, but when a project is huge enough it might not be a practical way...

Comment: What do you hope `p PRINT_CONCAT` would actually print, given that `PRINT_CONCAT` is a function-like macro?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was looking for `macro expand`. Have not heard about it before...

Comment: Macro expansion is something that happens at compile time, so a debugging session is a poor context in which to explore it.  Gdb may nevertheless be able to help you out with that a bit, but what you really ought to do is run the preprocessor (only) on some example code, and examine the result.  Since you are using gcc, you can use the command `gcc -E` to do the preprocessing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree with that, but the output of `gcc -E` might be very noisy and it's usually required to extract `compile_command` fragment for the specific file to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned to be as easy as [macro expand](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html)

```
(gdb) macro expand PRINT_CONCAT(2, 4)                                                                                                                                                                              
expands to: printf("%d\n", 24)
```

`-ggdb3` is not even required, `-g3` is enough. `-g2` does not seem to include the desired information.

Comment: Really nice job on figuring out how to do this given other commenters telling you to use the preprocessor because they didn't know the answer.

Comment: You may want to mention `info macro PRINT_CONCAT` as well (the title of your question asks for the macro definition, while the body asks for the expansion).